Container definition deployed by terraform loses mount_points and port_mappings
I am trying to deploy an aws_ecs_task_definition with two containers that share an EBS volume. Terraform will successfully run the deployment and update the task/container definitions but port_mappings and mount_points are never present in the container definitions when view in AWS.
locals {
  volume_name = "ebs_test"
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs_test" {
  availability_zone = "zone"
  size = 51

  tags = {
    Name = local.volume_name
  }
}

data "aws_ecr_image" "container_1_image" {
  repository_name = "Container1"
  image_tag = "latest"
}

data "aws_ecr_image" "container_2_image" {
  repository_name = "Container2"
  image_tag = "latest"
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "test_task" {
  family = "container_family"
  requires_compatibilities = ["EC2"]
  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn
  task_role_arn = aws_iam_role.execution_role.arn
  placement_constraints {
    type = "memberOf"
    expression = "ec2InstanceId == ${module.instance.instance_id}"
  }

  volume {
    name = local.volume_name
    docker_volume_configuration {
      scope = "shared"
      autoprovision = true
      driver = "rexray/ebs"
    }
  }

  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name = "Container1"
      memory = 256
      essential = true
      image = "${var.account_id}.dkr.ecr.${var.region}.amazonaws.com/${data.aws_ecr_image.container_1_image.repository_name}:latest@${data.aws_ecr_image.container_1_image.image_digest}"
      mount_points = [
        {
          container_path = "/mnt/${local.volume_name}"
          source_volume = local.volume_name
        }
      ]
      port_mappings = [
        {
          host_port = 80
          container_port = 80
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name = "Container2"
      memory = 256
      image = "${var.account_id}.dkr.ecr.${var.region}.amazonaws.com/${data.aws_ecr_image.container_2_image.repository_name}:latest@${data.aws_ecr_image.container_2_image.image_digest}"
      mount_points = [
        {
          source_volume = local.volume_name
          container_path = "/mnt/${local.volume_name}"
        }
      ]
      port_mappings = [
        {
          host_port = 80
          container_port = 80
        }
      ]
    }
  ])
}

This is what is always present in the task JSON pulled from AWS:
"portMappings": [],
"mountPoints": [],

Terraform apparently isn't seeing the port_mappings or mount_points properties being set when checking terraform plan:
      ~ container_definitions    = jsonencode(
          ~ [
              ~ {
                  - cpu              = 0
                  ~ memory           = 256 -> 512
                  - mountPoints      = []
                    name             = "Container1"
                  - portMappings     = []
                  - systemControls   = []
                  - volumesFrom      = []
                    # (4 unchanged attributes hidden)
                },
              ~ {
                  - cpu              = 0
                  - mountPoints      = []
                    name             = "Container2"
                  - portMappings     = []
                  - systemControls   = []
                  - volumesFrom      = []
                    # (5 unchanged attributes hidden)
                },
            ] # forces replacement
        )


I have been trying to use this GitHub repo is a reference: https://github.com/markgllin/ecs_with_ebs
What am I missing?

What versions of Terraform, and the AWS Terraform Provider, are you using? Also, does the terraform plan actually show the portMappings and mountPoints values you would expect? Also are you sure you are looking at the latest version of the task definition? Or could you be looking at the version of the task definition that is currently in use by a task?

Terraform v1.5.3 and yes I am sure to check the latest revision. To your terraform plan point, the mountPoints and portMappings are empty there too.

You are using the names mount_points and port_mappings in your Terraform code, but Terraform is looking for the names mountPoints and portMappings (as you can see in the Terraform plan output).

Ah yeah, just figured that out. Thanks for helping me narrow it down.

I'm just surprised Terraform didn't give a warning about an unrecognized setting in the task definition. I assumed it would do that.

It doesn't seem to care so long as you don't provide a malformed definition for a field it knows about. When troubleshooting I added a nonsense field as a sanity check but it still deployed it without failure.

Apparently it was simply the format for the strings. They needed to be camel-case and not under bar style. mount_points -> mountPoints etc.
